# How to select sharing image with next-share?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm trying to share an article from my website on LinkedIn/Facebook/Twitter. To do this, I'm using the **next-share** library. The issue is that after I click on the "share" icon, a link to the article I want to share opens, but the image there is selected in a completely incomprehensible way to me.

I need the main article image to be displayed, for example NEWS_IMAGES.FIRST_NEWS_IMG. But instead, on one article I get a back arrow icon, on another article I get a person's photo from the text, and on two other articles everything comes correctly.
[Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDCVL.png)
[Wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LqHc.png)
I tried to use the image prop, but it simply doesn't exist. I also tried to insert an image using <meta...>, but that didn't work either.

We need to make an explicit reference to the image that will be displayed when trying to share the article.
My website is built with Next.js and TypeScript.

```
            <LinkedinShareButton
              url={'https://example.com/en/news/1'}
              title={some title}
            >
              <StyledShareIcon alt='social network' src={ICONS.LINKEDIN} />
            </LinkedinShareButton>
```

Comment: Hi! Did you figure this out?